# append pandas dataframe automatically cast as float but want int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bitstring

How do I get pandas to append an integer and keep the integer data type? I realize I can df.test.astype(int) to the entire column after I have put in the data but if I can do it at the time I'm appending the data it seems like that would be a better way. Here is a sample:

```
from bitstring import BitArray
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

test = BitArray('0x01')
test = int(test.hex)
print(test)
df = df.append({'test':test, 'another':5}, ignore_index=True)

print(df.test)
print(df.another)
```

Here is the output:

```
1
0    1.0
Name: test, dtype: float64
0    5.0
Name: another, dtype: float64
```

It is changing the integers to floats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because your initial dataframe is empty.  Initialize it with some integer column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[], test=[], another=[]), dtype=int)
df.append(dict(A=3, test=4, another=5), ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

---

Had I done

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.append(dict(A=3, test=4, another=5), ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to do different dtypes per column?

Comment: @kaminsknator yes. When I need this, I usually write, for instance, `df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=pd.Series([], dtype=int), another=pd.Series([], dtype='category'), test=pd.Series([], dtype=float)))`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use convert_dtypes, if you are using Pandas 1.0.0 and above. Refer link for description and use [convert_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.convert_dtypes.html)

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
df = df.append({'test':test, 'another':5}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

As in this issue: [df.append should retain columns type if same type #18359](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18359), `append` method will retain column types since pandas 0.23.0.

So upgrading pandas version to 0.23.0 or newer solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 workarounds, I found.

1. Upgrade to pandas version `>= 0.23.0`
2. But if one cannot change pandas version like when working for production code and version change might affect other scripts/codes in `prod` environment.
   so below one-liner is a quick workaround.

`df = df.astype(int)`