# df.append() with dicts converts booleans to 1s and 0s

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Say I create an empty dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

and I add a dict via `df.append()`:

```
df.append({'A': 'foo', 'B': 'bar'}, ignore_index=True)
```

This gives me the intended result of

```
     A    B
0  foo  bar
```

However, if there are any booleans in the dict values, i.e.,

```
df.append({'A': True, 'B': False}, ignore_index=True)
```

The booleans are converted into floats.

```
     A    B
0  1.0  0.0
```

Why this is happening / how can I prevent this conversion? I'd prefer not do anything to the finished dataframe if possible (i.e., prefer not to coerce from float back to boolean).

**EDIT**: found my own solution, but still would like to know why the above behavior is happening. My solution is:

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': True, 'B': False}, orient='index').T, ignore_index=True)
```

Which gives the desired

```
      A      B
0  True  False
```

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513066/append-pandas-dataframe-automatically-cast-as-float-but-want-int) solves your issue. I guess it would only work if you have a single dtype DataFrame.

Comment: You should be able to initialize the empty dataframe as type bool.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your dict to a DataFrame before appending to keep the data types consistent:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.append(pd.DataFrame({'A': True, 'B': False}, index = [0]))


     A      B
0   True    False
```